# Prism Xamarin.Forms monoandroid81 Add a reference to "MonoAndroid

Tags: android, prism

I keep getting this error. (I'm using Android v8.1 and Prism default template)

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1"
framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" in the "frameworks"         
section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.d#    
PrismHelloWorld.Android
```

So I went into my project.assets.json and change the "monoandroid71" to "monoandroid81"

```
"originalTargetFrameworks": [
   "monoandroid71"
```

...

```
"monoandroid71": {
  "projectReferences": {
```

...

```
"frameworks": {
  "monoandroid71": {
```

I also changed

```
"projectFileDependencyGroups": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": [
```

and ...

```
"targets": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": {
```

I hit save and rebuild and it works absolutely fine! The problem is something is editing the json file and turning it all back to 71 and 7.1. I am not sure what is doing it but I will hit built and see the error again, about me needing a reference to v8.1.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to Android project Options -> Application -> Compile using Android version: (Target framework) and choose Android 8.1 (Oreo). Try different options

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on MvvmCross with Xamarin and I did your solution (changing "monoandroid71" to "monoandroid81" and "v7.1" to "v8.1") but it reverts back after closing and reopening the solution. What I did was do the same thing and do a "Restore NuGet Packages" at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will be working on it again this weekend 09/06/2018 and will post the solution when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

got the same issue, and able to fix it using below option,

[image]

Change the target version and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did was just restarted VS, and its back to normal

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by:

1. Right click Android project => Properties => Application => Compile using Android version => Android 7.1
2. Clean and Build project => build success, and restart IDE.
3. Right click Android project => Properties => Application => Compile using Android version => Android 8.1
4. Clean and Build project => build success
   File obj/project.assets.json updated to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1"